# coffee util when require(./module) takes .js file instead of .coffee

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, require, nodeclipse

I use CoffeeScript 1.6.3. While developing, I just run with `coffee myapp`.

I also run `coffee -c .` to examine resulted .js files.

However, when running `coffee myapp` again, coffee util for require(./module) takes .js file instead of .coffee. While usually latest code version is in .coffee files.

**Is it bug of coffe 1.6.3 util or there is some option to change that behavior?**

Comment: Would putting the output files in a different directory help?

Comment: Of course, there will not be this problem if to compile to other folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is run `coffee --watch` on my source tree, so whenever a .coffee file changes I immediately get it's .js counterpart.

Your imports will work fine, and you'll always have the latest .js from the latest .coffee as well.

Comment: Nice. I let `coffee -c -w .` run in Terminal View, that will make log of my changes. With this however I always have twice as many files (as all .coffee are compiled.)

Comment: My guess is they won't go for it: because "Coffeescript is just Javascript", and you may use Javascript modules in your code as well, the Javascript modules *must* `require` the .js version of the file. To prevent a mismatch, so should .coffee modules.

Comment: They said it is not Coffee but Node to blame.